# Disable IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Is there a way to disable IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2015? The information I find are all for the older version of VS, but not for VS 2015.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems to be impossible to really disable IntelliSense officially. When switching it off via `Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Advanced->Disable IntelliSense`
the database is still created. I.e. there is still a project.sdf next to your project.sln.

I found two ways of completely disabling it:

1. On project level: Delete project.sdf and create a folder with the same name. Now Visual Studio will give you a warning when you load the Solution that it can not create the Intellisense database
2. On system level: Uninstall Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4

Comment: works in 2017 as well. we have a struct .c file which was several hundred Ks,. intellisense would simply lock up VS on this file. forcing us to shut down VS.

Comment: The file with the intellisense database may be called differently, but replacing it with a folder helps anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Go to:

```
 Tools->Options->Text Editor->All Languanges
```

and there un-tick:

```
Auto List Members
```

and

```
Parameter information
```

Comment: Seems to do that. I found out that Ctr + Space still works. Is it completely disabled then?