# How can I disable this pop-up that appears during hover in the Visual Studio editor?

Tags: visual-studio

I've already turned off many options in Visual Studio 2017, but I can't suppress this annoying pop-up.  (Not this specific one, but all of them, for all the API's)

Can someone please show me the setting I need?

[image]

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36065496/369 ?

Comment: I already unselected "Auto List Members" and "Parameter Information" for C# and for All Languages.  The grey box still appears...perhaps the setting does not really work?

Answer (score 0):

Check this old post [How do I turn off code tooltips in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130598/how-do-i-turn-off-code-tooltips-in-visual-studio-2010). In it a workaround is provided but you will probably make a new extension from the source for it to work in Visual Studio 2017.
Looks like there is no setting for this except for the C/C++ language.