# How to disable floating tip about what System.String is in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to edit a big block of C# code with a lot of strings and Visual Studio keeps blocking my view and clicks with this:

[image]

It's the standard popup / floating tip / hint / hover message when you leave the cursor over any string which says:

> class System.String
>
> Represents text as a sequence of UTF-16 code units.To browse the .NET Framework source code for this type, see the Reference Source.

Is it possible to disable this just for the Strings? Or, worst case scenario, can I disable all tooptips? I wasn't able to find how to disable all IntelliSense though, only parts of it, and I don't know if it's a function of IntelliSense, so maybe it wouldn't help.

As a workaround, I'm currently going up the code instead of down, because if I move cursor down, it gets onto the hover tip and it just stays there, but upwards I can see the code and click where I want. But this is annoying and I'd like to find a normal solution.

Comment: You can hold Ctrl to make the tooltip (and IntelliSense popups) transparent. Or just take care where you position your mouse pointer. I have to admit not having that problem so far.

Comment: Being able to disable tooltips on a per-type basis seems like a level of specificity I wouldn't expect to find out-of-the-box; perhaps there's an extension that allows that kind of customization.  I'm curious what you're doing that you keep moving and leaving your mouse hovering over `string`s, and why you have this problem with `string`s but evidently not other types/values.

Comment: All I'm doing is double-clicking one string, copying it to another place, then going down the line trying to select the string below and the tip appears and I can't click through it even with Ctrl held down. Try double-clicking strings positioned on each line in a column and see if it's easy. Maybe there is a global system variable for how long it takes for the tips to appear? Like the double-click timeout duration?

Comment: Can you share a sample of the kind of code you're editing? It's line after line of string property/field/variable definitions? When you are "copying it to another place" is that solely using the keyboard and without moving the mouse? I do see that if I hover over a string and tab to another document the tooltip will reappear when I tab back without moving the mouse. I realize none of this answers your actual question, but I'm just trying to ascertain if there's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) going on here since, like @Joey, this is not a problem I've ever experienced.

Comment: I mean I could use an option to disable all tooltips at this point because whenever I leave the cursor over a string, it only takes a second for the tooltip to activate, and then wherever I move the cursor, if it lands on any text, that shows a tooltip in half a second. So I have to wiggle the cursor around or out of the text-populated area for the tooltip to disappear so I can click what I actually want behind it. I just happen to be getting them on strings because I'm trying to select them, but honestly it could be any other text. So I might just be looking for "Disable all tooltips" option.

Comment: [How can I disable this pop-up that appears during hover in the Visual Studio editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47521000/150605) asks about such an option for Visual Studio 2017 and links to a solution (extension) that works for Visual Studio 2010 but apparently nothing newer.